# What does *~ do in a .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I just ran across a gitignore file that ends with the line *~ but I have not been able to find a description of what this does.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It ignores all files whose name ends in `~`, which is a usual suffix for text editors backup files.

`*` is a special symbol and means *"any sequence of zero or more characters"*, while `~` is just an ordinary character. Putting the two parts together: *"zero or more characters followed by a ~"*.

Comment: This is a very nice, and concise answer, with explanation. Nicely done.

Answer (score 6):

It tells Git to ignore all files that end with a tilde (~), which is used by many text editors such as Emacs or Vi to mark temporary files.